# wxWidgets lots of undefined references

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I downloaded the source to the latest wx and managed to compile it without any issues.

Configured with:

```
../configure --enable-optimise --enable-stl --enable-unicode --enable-threads --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
```

When I try to compile [this](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html) example with:

```
g++-4.8 `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags` test.cpp
```

I get alot of undefined refferences ( full list [here](http://pastebin.com/k2p9U9MR) )

How can I make this work?

Comment: could you test the following?: g++ `wx-config --cppflags` `wx-config --libs` test.cpp

Comment: Same errors ( I added the needed ` , doesn't work without it )

Comment: You have got problems with the linker if you are in linux, make sure you have installed wx libraries before, test it with: wx --version. Recall you have to add libs to LD_LIBRARY for configuring a dynamic linker.

Comment: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started

Comment: I followed that tutorial, same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using static libraries, as you do (because of `--disable-shared` in configure command line), the libraries must come **after** the object file that references them (this is a general rule with all Unix-ish linkers and definitely with GNU ld). So the correct command line would be

```
g++-4.8 `wx-config --cxxflags` test.cpp `wx-config --libs`
```

or, just to keep it short, and because it does *not* matter where do the compilation flags appear:

```
g++-4.8 test.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the wx libraries so the linker can resolve the references.

Comment: `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags` does that