# Reference errors when linking wxWidgets statically

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, static-libraries, premake

I'm using [this Premake4 script for wxWidgets](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Premake4) in my build script:

```
wx_config {Unicode="yes", Version="2.9", Libs="core,aui,media,html", WindowsCompiler="gcc", Static="yes"}
```

But CodeBlocks respectively MinGW outputs many errors:

```
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxbase29u.a(baselib_filename.o):filename.cpp:(.text+0x5371): undefined reference to `CoCreateInstance@20'
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxbase29u.a(baselib_filename.o):filename.cpp:(.text+0x5390): undefined reference to `IID_IPersistFile'
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw29u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x7cc9): undefined reference to `wxEVT_POWER_SUSPEND_CANCEL'
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw29u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x7cf9): undefined reference to `vtable for wxPowerEvent'
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw29u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x7d55): undefined reference to `wxEVT_POWER_SUSPENDED'
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw29u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x7d61): undefined reference to `wxEVT_POWER_SUSPENDING'
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw29u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x7d6d): undefined reference to `wxEVT_POWER_RESUME'
wx\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw29u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x7f18): undefined reference to `vtable for wxPowerEvent'
...
```

You can see all linker errors here: http://pastebin.com/UGSRg4DX

Someone mentioned in a wxWidgets bug report<sub>(link lost)</sub> that the library order is causing this problem. But he didn't say which library has to be put first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like exactly the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393322/wxwidgets-lots-of-undefined-refferences/12395262#12395262). I.e. you need to put the libraries in your premake script in the right order: `aui,media,html,core` (the important thing is that "core" is the last one). Also, I don't know if it's appended implicitly perhaps but normally you'd also need "base" at the very end.

Comment: Thanks. My library order in Codeblocks is `wxpngd, wxzlibd, wxmsw29ud_adv, wxmsw29ud_core, wxbase29ud` but now I get undefined reference errors for `ImageList_*` and `png_*` functions.

Comment: `ImageList_` are from the standard `comctl32.lib` library. `png_` are, of course, from `libpng`. You need to link with both (and put them both at the end).

Comment: Is `libpng` the same as `wxpngd`? I've put them both to the library list in Codeblocks, but now I'm getting undefined `OleInitialize` reference errors.

Comment: Please use MSDN to look up the libraries for the standard Windows functions. Or just copy their full list from a makefile of any wxWidgets sample.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW Compiler is not well suited for wxwidgets. Even I have tried to compile my project with MinGW GCC compiler. But I can get success after so much of attempts.

Same thing I have done with TDM-GCC compiler first. Latter I tried with MSYS64 compiler also. And results was fine.

Both of them were able to compile the project.

So I will suggest you to use any of compiler than except MinGW.